# Authorized public URL keeps redirecting for authentication and failing

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In this scenario, `OurCustomAuth` is currently returning an expected value of *false*, is reaching the appropriate else, but the `users/error` path keeps redirecting even though it's been made public and not requiring any authentication.

I've setup the new action:

```
C:\wamp\myapp\app>Console\cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_update

Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.9 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: C:\wamp\myapp\app\
---------------------------------------------------------------
Created Aco node: controllers/Users/error
Aco Update Complete
```

In the `UsersController`, I've added the action to be made public:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter ();
    $this->Auth->allow ('logout', 'error');
}
```

In `AppController`, the `Auth` config:

```
public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Cookie',
    'DebugKit.Toolbar', 'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array('OurCustomAuth'),
        'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'),
        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
        'authorize' => array('Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers'))
    )
);

...
public function beforeFilter() {
    ...

    //Auto logging users in if they are not logged in
    if (!AuthComponent::user('id')) {

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {

            //stuff here

        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('We could not authenticate you ...'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'error'));
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

The error I get in Firefox:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.

**Update #1**

`$this->Auth->login()` essentially grabs request headers, that in this case are intentionally wrong, which seems to redirect to the appropriate link. However, `/users/error` shouldn't cause a redirect as it's excluded from Authentication.

Comment: Are you sure that the controllers `beforeFilter()` method is being invoked at all? Also where _exactly_ is the `if (!AuthComponent::user('id')) { ...` code being executed?

Comment: AppController's beforeFilter() method.

Comment: That would probably explain it... please update your code example to reflect where the code is located, in order for future readers to be able to understand the problem properly.

Comment: Updated code... explain it how? Should I add Auth->allow in the AppController's beforeFilter?

Comment: I'm a little bit busy right now, I'll post an answer later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you run your login code on every request, ie in the app controllers `beforeFilter()` method. So when that code redirects you to `/users/error` because you're not logged in, the code will run again for that controller/action, and redirect you again, and again, and again...

If you need to run this code for every request, then you'll have to check the allowed actions manually, ie the actions allowed via `$this->Auth->allow()`, and run your code only in case the current action isn't allowed. Check the code of **[`AuthComponent::_isAllowed()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.9/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L323)**, you can easily use that with minimal modifications:

```
$action = strtolower($this->request->params['action']);
if (!in_array($action, array_map('strtolower', $this->Auth->allowedActions))) {
    //Auto logging users in if they are not logged in
    if (!AuthComponent::user('id')) {
        // ...
    }
}
```